# Safari rounds large number in HTML5 input number field

Tags: html, browser, safari, biginteger

My web app has a number field that accepts arbitrarily large numbers. However, In Safari, a large number is rounded in the HTML5 number field: `<input type="number>`. For example, a number "1234567890123456" is rounded to "1234567890123460". Chrome and firfox doesn't do this. Is there a way to get around this in Safari?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no ways other than using type=text.
[Number input can handle only IEEE 754 double-precision numbers](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#floating-point-numbers). It can't handle arbitrary higher precision.

Comment: Looks like an "integer" as defined by Javascript is a 64-bit number (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-max-int-whats-the-highest-integer-value-a-number-can-go-t). So I guess I will have to use "text" type.